# How to extend standard screen F-41

Tags: abap, sap-erp, dynpro, badi

I need to extend T-code F-41 for `Xref1_HD`, `Xref2_HD`.

I know there is a BAdI but I have never used neither enhancements nor BAdIs, because I am still learning.

There is a Dynpro `1300` and BAdI `FI_HEADER_SUB_1300`, but I really do not know how to use it.

Also I found `SAPLBADI_EXAMPLE_1300` and used it in my implementation. Is it possible to create a `Z`program and an own Dynpro to use it?

Comment: the BAdI is the Z-Program ... inside of it you can change the flow logic or add additional fields to the dynpro. you need to modify the PBO part to do this. check this: https://scn.sap.com/thread/297563

Answer (score 1):

You can use modification assistant or use Standard Enhancement pint. One thing do not forget regenerate structures if you are adding new fields. You have to run 3 reports: RFBIPPG0, RFBIPPG1, RFBIPPG3.